# what is the purpose of the -I option of the xargs command?

Tags: command-line, xargs

I looked into the integrated manual of the xargs command, where the -I option is explained. And though I read the few lines repeatedly, I can not make any sense of it:

> -I replace-str
>                 Replace  occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.  Also, un‐
>                 quoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.  Implies -x  and
>                 -L 1.

Could you explain this to me with other words or give me a jump start by an example, which shows the importance of this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick pair of examples of `xargs -I` in action:

```
$ echo foo bar baz | xargs -I quux echo quux
foo bar baz
$ echo -e "foo\nbar\nbaz" | xargs -I quux echo quux
foo
bar
baz
```

`-I` means "Replace this marker with the newline-separated items coming in from standard input".

Comment: this was a great answer, it made sense in my brain.  echo thank | xargs -I xyz echo xyz you

Comment: @sharkant If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.